# Verify file copied using copy-item

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-5.0

i'm trying to copy file from source to destination any verify if file copied or not.

But the problem is if i make changes inside the source file which was copied earlier then destination file not getting override when i execute the code again. Also i want log file each time files are copied.

**Files in folder:-** .csv, .log, .png, .html

```
$source="C:\52DWM93"
$destination="C:\Temp\"
Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $destination -Force
$ver=(Get-ChildItem -file -path $destination -Recurse).FullName | foreach {get-filehash $_ -Algorithm md5}
If($ver)
{Write-Host "ALL file copied"}
else
{Write-Host "ALL file not copied"}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you copy directories like this you *need* the -Recurse switch for `Copy-Item`. Without it you're not going to copy anything except the directory itself.

You can of course also use Get-ChildItem with whatever filter or Recurse flag you care about and pipe that into `Copy-Item`.

Use the `*-FileCatalog` cmdlets for verification.

Comment: If you are on Windows, then use robocopy.exe instead.  See the robocopy.exe help file for details, switches, and examples.